# Existence of mixed strategies for a given payoff

Tags: game-theory

Let  be a zero-sum matrix game, and let ****p**
′**
, ****p**
″** be mixed strategies
for Rose and **q
′
, q
″** mixed strategies for Colin. Suppose the expected
payoff when Rose plays **p
′**
and Colin plays **q
′**
is ′
and the expected
payoff when Rose plays **p
″** and Colin plays **q
″**
is ″
. If ′ <  < ″
,
show that there exist mixed strategies **p** for Rose and **q** for Colin so
that the expected payoff when Rose plays **p** and Colin plays **q** is .

I am studying Game Theory: A Playful Introduction
Book by Deborah A. Kent and Matthew Jared DeVos.
I need to solve this question using only basic concepts like expected payoff, mixed strategy, and Minimax theorem. The question reminds me of the intermediate value property.

Any hints please?

Comment: I would expect that convex combinations of the two strategies give you a payoff that varies continuously between $w'$ and $w''$.

Comment: @RobertShore I understand the hint but I am not able to prove this. Could you elaborate on how to show continuity

Comment: The payoff function is a fixed linear combination of the components of the strategy.